# How do I plot fig and axes in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was doing this tutorial, but sadly I cant figure out how to show the first plot in Spyder.

Tutorial:
https://www.sonofacorner.com/figuring-figures-out-a-matplotlib-tutorial/

Code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,2))
# The rect parameter [left, bottom, width, height]
ax = fig.add_axes(rect = [0,0,1,1])
```

So we added the axes to the created fig but if I run the code it just shows a empty fig
without any axes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is simpler: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2))`

Comment: this just creates an empty `fig` and `ax`, and then you need to plot onto the axes, e.g. `ax.plot(......)`

Comment: Are you using an IDE ?

Comment: @tdy think this is an IDE issue. He doesn't even get the plots. I tried this in PyCharm I am getting a blank window. Works in Notebooks.

Comment: @tdy Do you mean like this: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 2))`

`ax.plot([0.5,2,2,0.5,0.5],[1,1,0.5,0.5,1])`

Comment: @kgkmeeg Yes, I'm using an IDE. Couldn't find out how to plot it there

Comment: @PaiThon yes, and also `plt.show()` at the end. if that doesn't work, i guess it's an IDE issue

Comment: A problem with `rect = [0,0,1,1]`, is that the inner plot covers the complete figure, leaving no space for ticks and labels.  It is highly recommended to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(...))`.  Also note that a `figsize` with a height of 2 is extremely small, making it hard to properly show labels. As such, (the start of) the linked tutorial seems to lack quality. It might work somewhat inside a Jupyter notebook (which automatically does some resizing).

Comment: FWIW, that does not look like a great `matplotlib` tutorial. The ones in the `matplotlib` docs are much better: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html -- just my opinion.

Comment: I'll have a look at it @kwinkunks and JohanC yea, i did i know with the tutorial from matplotlib.org itself as mentioned from tdy